# if conditional form field has value, find it's required child field

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I have a conditional field, that when it gets a value; it displays another field, that will be '***required***' underneath it...

Currently, the field underneath is being skipped by my python script - I'm trying to do a check with the below logic to find the field. `answer` is the variable containing the value of input fields.

```
conditional_field = '//*[@id="qna_0"]/fieldset[1]/fieldset[20]/div[2]/div/input'
    hfield = "//*[@id='qna_0']/fieldset[1]/fieldset[21]/div[2]/div/textarea"

    if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(conditional_field).get_attribute('value') == answer:
        pass
        if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(hfield).get_attribute('value') == answer:
            pass
            self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#publishButton").click()
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-mini.btn-primary"))).click()
        else:
           sleep(40) 
    else: 
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#publishButton").click()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-mini.btn-primary"))).click()
```

**any ideas on how to accomplish this?** *(and/or whats bad about the above?)*

Comment: can you uncomment to ensure it's not something silly like indentation?

Comment: It's certainly not indentation - that is always my first check LOL

Comment: ok, just never seen a question from a serious user posted with comment marks...

Comment: good luck with that!